# PowerShell add Task to run PowerShell script with parameters

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying add a Task to the Task Scheduler from a PowerShell script that will run a PowerShell script with parameters.

The spaces in the file path are conflicting with the necessary quotes surrounding the whole command, and SCHTASKS converts ' to " so I can't encapsulate properly.

```
$command = "PowerShell \`"& 'C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1' $myStringParam $myBooleanParam\'"" 
Write-Host $command # This outputs: PowerShell \"& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1' Cat 0\"  
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "MyTask" /TR "$command" /SC DAILY /ST 01:30:00 /RL Highest /EC ScriptEvents /RU SYSTEM
```

but Task Scheduler shows Actions as:

```
PowerShell "& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1" Cat 0"
```

The " and " cancel each other out because ' is always switched to " here, thus task fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using \" as the inner quotes. Had to swap ' with \\\`" in PowerShell script

```
$command = "PowerShell \`"& \\\`"C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1\\\`" $myStringParam $myBooleanParam\'""
```

So Task Scheduler shows

```
PowerShell "& \"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1\" Cat 0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the -File parameter of powershell.exe to specify the script to run and just add the parameters of the script at the end

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1" Cat 0
```

**UPDATE**

Boolean and Switch parameters seem to be a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079413/how-to-pass-boolean-values-to-powershell-script-from-command-prompt) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367685/powershell-how-do-i-pass-variables-to-switch-parameters-when-invoking-powershel) [-File](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/742084/powershell-v2-powershell-cant-convert-false-into-swtich-when-using-file-param). This will work:

```
powershell.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyDir\MyScript.ps1" Cat 0
```

Comment: Tried that many times, doesn't work because then PowerShell can't translate the 0 (or $false) to boolean from the string.

Comment: @Brent: Seems to be a known problem. Updated my answer with a fix

Answer (score 0):

Use the  **-command** parameter for powershell:

What you would execute in your powershell without task sceulder:

```
C:\Scripts\mypsscript.ps1 -parameter 'nice value'
```

What you give the task sceduler:

Programm to run: 
Powershell

Arguments:

```
-Command "& C:\Scripts\mypsscript.ps1 -parameter 'nice value'"
```