# Powershell - Schedule a Task to run a PS script with parameters

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a task that runs a PS script with parameters. But I believe I'm missing an escape character somewhere or my ' and " are in the wrong place. I can't seem to get it to work properly without it splitting the action argument. Below is my code:

```
    $employeeID = "1234"
    $employee = "email@email.com"
    $restoretime = (Get-date).AddHours(12)
    $restoreuser = "$($employee) Offboarding"
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -once -At $restoretime 
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute    '%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Argument `
    -Command "& 'C:\Location\testing.ps1' -employeeID '$($employeeID)' -employee '$($employee)'"
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $restoreuser -Action $taskAction -Trigger $trigger
```

I get this result (see image)[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723940/powershell-add-task-to-run-powershell-script-with-parameters) with no luck!

Comment: I think you need to wrap the whole `-Argument` in `"`. Escape the `"` inside the argument with ` (backtick).

Comment: remove the things in "Start in (optional) and add the following in "Add arguments (optional)": ```-NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -file "C:\Location\testing.ps1"```

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping the -Argument worked! I had always tried wrapping it from the -Command.

I did try the -file but the task just won't run (I had tried it before), the task exits with 0X01